# Bootstrap 3 column and input field

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to stretch an input text to fit all width of the parent bootstrap column?

```html
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-5">
  <span class="pull-right">
  <div class="row buttons-block">
    <div class="col-md-8">              
      <input type="text" class="form-control name-pull-image">              
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary pull-image-button">Pull Firmware</button> 
    </div>
  </div>
  </span>
</div>
```

[image: DevTools screen]

Comment: Using css, target the DOM Element and set it to `width: 100%;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue using the following code:

```html
<div class="col-md-5">
  <snan class="input-group pull-right" style="width: 99%;">
    <input type="text" class="form-control name-pull-image">
    <span class="input-group-addon btn-primary btn-block btn-flat pull-image-button" style="width: 70px;">Pull Firmware</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-5">
            <span class="pull-right">
                <div class="row buttons-block">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control name-pull-image">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary pull-image-button">Pull Firmware</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </span>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not put the "pull-right" within the div itself instead of putting it inside the span?

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-5 pull-right">
  <div class="row buttons-block">
    <div class="col-md-8">              
      <input type="text" class="form-control name-pull-image">           
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary pull-image-button">Pull Firmware</button> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```